# Passing command in array to open

Tags: windows, perl

I have a command with arguments prepared in an Perl array `@cmd`. The ultimate goal is to execute that command and capture output lines in variable. Under linux, I do it via opening the pipe, exec the command in child and capture it in parent. But that doesn't seem to work in Windows (I get an error `'-' is not recognized as an internal or external command`).

I noticed something like this does work though:

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'dir') or die $!;
my @output = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

My question is how to pass `@cmd` to `open()`? Or is there other simpler way to capture command output in Windows?

Also few notes - `@cmd` is prepared in the fly, so I don't know how it looks at the time when executing `open()`. And I can only use core functions, no third party packages.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple like backticks/`qx`/`readpipe`? Or do you need the intermediate output?

Comment: How do I convert `@cmd` to be used with backticks?

Answer (score 4):

Support for `open(my $fh, '-|', 'dir')` was only added to Windows in 5.22. Before that, only the two-arg version was available.

```
open(my $fh, 'dir |')
```

If you need to build a command, you'd need to use something equivalent to

```
use Win32::ShellQuote qw( quote_system_string );

my $cmd = quote_system_string($prog, @args);
open(my $fh, "$cmd |")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So would something like `open(my $fh, join(' ', @cmd) . ' |')` be correct? Would the arguments in `@cmd` be correctly escaped..?

Comment: `"@cmd"` is more straightforward then using `join`. You haven't said what `@cmd` might contain. What escaping do you think you have to worry about?

Comment: Both `join(' ', @cmd)` and `"@cmd"` will quote improperly. Imagine if one of the elements of `@cmd` contains spaces `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`, etc. Updated my answer.

Comment: What I meant by escaping is that some of the command arguments might contain spaces, e.g. 'a -x b'. If its not properly escaped, this argument might be split and passed to the command as three instead of one, as an example.

Comment: Thanks ikegami for the updated snippet. I have command and all arguments in `@cmd`, so I don't need `$prog`. 

Is there any other way, if I didn't want libraries not in core?

Comment: Depends on exactly what problem you have with modules not in core. Can't tell you how to work around the problem if I don't know what it is.